# Hybris backoffice - display of attributes in correct tab

Tags: configuration, e-commerce, sap-commerce-cloud, b2b, backoffice

In backoffice, for **B2BUnit** and **B2BCustomer** models, There are some important attributes that are displaying under "*Administration*" tab.
But I would like to show it under "***Properites***" or "***General***" tab. What configuration I need to change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope you already have a custom backoffice extension, if not then follow [this tutorial](https://help.sap.com/viewer/5c9ea0c629214e42b727bf08800d8dfa/1905/en-US/8bd2f59e86691014859ba68181c14710.html?q=custom%20backoffice) to create one.

Now, In your custom backoffice extension, you can find the file ***backoffice-backoffice-config.xml**. In this file, you can define how & where you want to populate your custom attribute. You need to declare it for the editor-area component like below.

```
<context merge-by="type" parent="Customer" type="B2BCustomer" component="editor-area">
    <editorArea:editorArea xmlns:editorArea="http://www.hybris.com/cockpitng/component/editorArea">
        <editorArea:tab xmlns="http://www.hybris.com/cockpitng/component/editorArea" name="hmc.properties">
            <section name="hmc.section.your.custom.section">
                <attribute qualifier="yourAttribute"/>
            </section>
        </editorArea:tab>
    </editorArea:editorArea>
</context>
```

Here you can define the new custom section (**hmc.section.your.custom.section**) or use any existing section name. For the custom section, you need to define its value in the in labels_en.properties (like a way for each language labels_*.properties) file.